# Adding controls to a Panel in an UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a Panel in an UpdatePanel, a Button and a TextBox.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="commentBox" Rows="1" Columns="60" placeholder="Add a comment..." TextMode="MultiLine" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
    <asp:LinkButton ID="commentButton" runat="server" OnClick="commentButton_Click"> CommentButton   </asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:Panel ID="commentPanel" runat="server"></asp:Panel>   
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

on Button Click I am trying add what's in the TextBox to the Panel like this

```
Literal myComment = new Literal();
myComment.Text = "<p>"+commentBox.Text+"</p><br />";
commentPanel.Controls.Add(myComment);
```

This adds whats currently in the TextBox, but what was there in the panel gets removed.
So every time it starts from 0 count for controls in the panel. what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check this out:

```
List<Literal> persistControls = new List<Literal>();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // if you already have some literal populated
    if (Session["persistControls"] != null)
    {
        // pull them out of the session
        persistControls = (List<Literal>)Session["persistControls"];
        foreach (Literal ltrls in persistControls)
            commentPanel.Controls.Add(ltrls); // and push them back into the page
    }
}

protected void commentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Literal myComment = new Literal();
    myComment.Text = "<p>" + commentBox.Text + "</p><br />";
    commentPanel.Controls.Add(myComment);
    persistControls.Add(myComment);// add it to the list
    Session["persistControls"] = persistControls; // put it in the session
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. the other one worked so i didnt try this. but thanks again.

Comment: i might actually need to try this. because the added controls go away when i click another button that is not related to this at all.

Comment: yes this works better. thing i don't quite understand is i thought updatepanel worked asynchronously so when i add controls i thought it would preserve them but guess not.

Answer (score 1):

```
     Literal comment = new Literal();
    comment.Text="";

    Panel1.Controls.Add(comment);
    if (Panel1.Controls.Contains(comment))
    {
        comment.Text = comment.Text + "<p>" + commentbox.Text + "</p>";
    }
```

Comment: This is working on button click event and Panel1 refers to commentpanel in your code